# WordPress - SQL request with WP_Query, use OR between post_type and taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

My issue is pretty simple, I'm trying to get both portfolio posts (from a plugin) and articles that have the "portfolio" category (made myself).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'portfolio',
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

It looks like the relationship between post_type and tax_query is an AND, I'd need an OR, how can I do that?

I tried following the official documentation but I'm stuck. (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with a relation 'OR':

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR', /* <-- here */
        array(
            'key' => 'color',
            'value' => 'blue',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => array( 20, 100 ),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: This makes an OR between the two meta queries, right ? So basically if the color is NOT LIKE blue OR the price in between 20 and 100. But it is still an AND with the port_type = "portfolio".

Comment: @Vadorequest I think you'll have to do two different WP_Query and merge the results.

Comment: Seriously? That's exactly what I shouldn't do. It's a really bad habit, and I don't even know how to merge the result since what's returned by WP_Query is an object, not an array or so. I thought about that but I'd rather prefer to do it with one query, that's what I'd do if I was using proper SQL strings.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any solution using only one query. (couldn't change the `AND` to `OR`).

So I've made two queries instead:

```
$query1 = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio'));
$query2 = new WP_Query(array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'portfolio',
        )
    )));

$query = merge_WP_queries($query1, $query2);

function merge_WP_queries(WP_Query $query1, WP_Query $query2){
    $wp_query_returned = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query_returned->posts = array_merge( $query1->posts, $query2->posts );

    //populate post_count count for the loop to work correctly
    $wp_query_returned->post_count = $query1->post_count + $query2->post_count;

    return $wp_query_returned;
}
```

It works correctly, even though it's not what I'd like to use.